# Is there a way to use control keys Bluetooth keyboard via Remote Desktop?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I use the Microsoft Remote Desktop app on my iPad for remote control. I would like to use shortcuts like 'alt + tab', 'ctrl + tab', etc. But I can't, because Microsoft Remote Desktop don't send 'alt' and 'ctrl'.
I tried VNC Viewer app, it work well, but I need support multiple connections(MRD can do it).
In the sum I need app which work through Windows Remote Desktop, and send 'alt' and 'ctrl' keys, or way to fix it  in Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Comment: what does "bt-keyboard" mean?

Comment: bluetooth keyboard